# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Returning Blank

Tags: php, html-parsing

I'm trying to get HTML DOM to work with a website but no matter how much I alter it, it doesn't work. Everything's just blank. Here's the code:

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = "http://beyonce.com";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
foreach($html->find('div[class=header-wrapper]') as $post)
{
echo $post."<br />";
}
?>
```

Site: http://beyonce.com!

Comment: div[id=header-wrapper]

Comment: Geez, I cannot believe I missed such a tiny thing! Thank you so so much @splash58 !